# accessing property in wrapped Ember.js component

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple component like this:

```
# app/components/outside-component.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  counter: 1
});
```

with its template defined as

```
# app/templates/components/outside-component.hbs
{{yield}}
```

and I want to render it inside of template like this

```
# app/templates/application.hbs

{{#outside-component}}
  {{counter}}
{{/outside-component}}
```

The counter is however not being render here and I think that's because the context is set to outer context. How do I render a component like this and enforce it to use the component scope?

Comment: Hi! am getting an error "The gist is missing or secret." when trying to look at the Ember Twiddle

Comment: sorry, removed the broken link, I'll add it back later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context of `application.hbs` is the application controller, counter is defined on the component unless you yield it from inside the component it will lookup `counter` on the controller.

**outside-component.hbs**
`{{yield counter}}`

**Application.hbs**

```
{{#outside-component as |counter|}}
  {{counter}}
{{/outside-component}}
```

[Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/3502fc71faf81fe758a99e865d7bbec6?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs)